# Invalid column name on SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently teaching myself SQL on SQL Server and came across this practice problem but the solution keeps running an invalid column for my column alias

QUESTION

> Select the name of each manufacturerer which having an average price above $145 and contain at least 2 different products.

SOLUTION

```
SELECT M.name, AVG(P.price) AS avgprice, COUNT(p.manufacturer) AS mancount
FROM manufacturers M, products P
WHERE p.manufacturer = m.code
GROUP BY p.manufacturer
HAVING avgprice >= 150 AND mancount >= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference column aliases in `HAVING`, only in `ORDER BY`. This is because the expressions in `HAVING` are processed *before* the `SELECT` list.

Try:

```
SELECT M.name, 
       AVG(P.price) AS avgprice, 
       COUNT(P.manufacturer) AS mancount
FROM dbo.manufacturers AS M
INNER JOIN dbo.products AS P
  ON P.manufacturer = M.code
GROUP BY P.manufacturer
HAVING AVG(P.price) >= 150 
  AND COUNT(P.manufacturer) >= 2;
```

A couple of other fixes:

- [Don't use old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (`FROM a, b`)
- Be [consistent with case](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-careless-about-case) (`P` <> `p` on case- or binary-sensitive collations)
- Always [reference tables with schema name](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference an alias in the `having` (or `where` or `group by`) clause. You have to repeat the calculation or calculate it in a sub-query e.g.

You also can't select a column you are not grouping or aggregating (`p.manufacturer`), I think you intended to group by `M.[name]`.

```
SELECT M.[name], AVG(P.price) AS avgprice, COUNT(P.manufacturer) AS mancount
FROM manufacturers AS M
INNER JOIN products AS P ON P.manufacturer = M.code
--WHERE P.manufacturer = M.code
GROUP BY M.[name]
--HAVING avgprice >= 150 AND mancount >= 2;
-- Repeat the calculation
HAVING AVG(P.price) >= 150 AND COUNT(P.manufacturer) >= 2;
```

Note: Its best practice to use explicit joins as I have shown rather than a comma join as you have used.

An example of a sub-query solution, which avoids having to repeat the calculation, is:

```
SELECT [name], avgprice, mancount
FROM (
    SELECT M.[name], AVG(P.price) AS avgprice, COUNT(P.manufacturer) AS mancount
    FROM manufacturers AS M
    INNER JOIN products AS P ON P.manufacturer = M.code
    GROUP BY M.[name]
) AS X
WHERE avgprice >= 150 AND mancount >= 2;
```

Comment: Hi Dale, for some reason the first solution only worked when I changed the group by from P.manufacturer to M.name due to a m.name being invalid in the select list not contained in either the aggregate or group by.

The second solution also runs into an error, "the multi-part identifier "m.name" could not be bound"

Comment: @hamdragon thats as your original query... what did you intend to group by?

Comment: Oh, I see where I made my mistake in what I posted. The solution I posted was one given in the answer section so I guess there were multiple mistakes on that. I apologize for the confusion.

I intended to group by the M.name so I do see the error.

I am unsure as to why the sub query solution is not working, I will take another look at that one to see if I made any errors. Thank you for your response!